# cmake: check if file exists at build time rather than during cmake configuration

Tags: file, cmake, exists

I have a custom build command that needs to check if a certain file exists. I tried using

```
IF(EXISTS "/the/file")
...
ELSE()
...
ENDIF()
```

but that test is only evaluated one; when cmake is first run. I need it to perform the test every time a make is done. What's the method to check at make-time? Thanks.

Comment: Show the rest of the custom build command.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:add_custom_command) to invoke CMake itself in script mode by using the [`-P`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#opt:-Pfile) command line option.

So your command would be something like:

```
set(FileToCheck "/the/file")
add_custom_command(TARGET MyExe
                   POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
                       -DFileToCheck=${FileToCheck}
                       -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/check.cmake
                   COMMENT "Checking if ${FileToCheck} exists...")
```

and your script file "check.cmake" would be something like:

```
if(EXISTS ${FileToCheck})
  message("${FileToCheck} exists.")
else()
  message("${FileToCheck} doesn't exist.")
endif()
```

Comment: Thanks, although it seems a lot of work just to check for a file :)

Comment: I understand this works, but I agree with @gimmeamilk it is tedious for such a simple thing. Still, I will vote up the solution.

Comment: May be, it would be worth to emphasize that your answer provides a portable solution. (We explicitly chose CMake for the development of applications which can be compiled on Windows as well as on Linux, and, may be, even on MacOS X. That's why I might be a bit sensitive concerning this.)

Comment: I'm here because I need something like this. Now, what if "/the/file" doesn´t exists, is it possible to ignore run/execute the target based on the non-existing file? Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work: `CMake Error: Error processing file: .../check.cmake`

Answer (score 4):

#### A similar idea

You're going to need `add_custom_command`, but if you're willing to be a little Unix specific you can always use [test](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html).

```
set(FileToCheck "/the/file")
add_custom_command( OUTPUT output.txt
    COMMAND test -e output.txt || echo "Do something meaningful"
    COMMENT "Checking if ${FileToCheck} exists...")
```

Comment: `COMMAND test -e output.txt || echo "Do something if file does not exist"` <br/>
`COMMAND test ! -e output.txt || echo "Do something if file exist"`

Comment: @idailylife maybe a little more detail? The comments section ignores HTML

Answer (score 1):

[@Frazers] answer is great if you need to add custom logic inside the if(EXISTS).
However, if you just need your build to fail if a single file is missing you can use the `cmake -E` command line mode to compare the file with itself.

This will make sure the build always stops if the provided file doesn't exist, it's cross-platform safe and works in every version of cmake since 3.0.

```
set(_fileToCheck "foo.txt")
add_custom_command(TARGET YourTarget
  PRE_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E compare_files ${_fileToCheck} ${_fileToCheck}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  COMMENT "Checking if ${_fileToCheck} exists, build will fail if it doesn't"
)
```