# CMAKE: Force that if a files exists then it is up-to-date (at build)

Tags: cmake

I am using cmake to build a paper, which has an involved build process.

1. Build an exe
2. run the exe to generate some data (in ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/data)
3. run some python to process the data into figures (Postscript images). These are saved in ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/fig.
4. convert images to png
5. build a latex document with those figures

This can all be done in cmake by chaining the outputs of custom_commands to custom targets:

```
#This is the command that does the work (run python, or some executable etc.).  Will only run if ${CUSTOM_DEPENDS} is newer that ${CUSTOM_OUTPUT}
add_custom_command( OUTPUT ${CUSTOM_OUTPUT}
        COMMAND ${CUSTOM_COMMAND}
        DEPENDS ${CUSTOM_DEPENDS}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CUSTOM_WORKING_DIRECTORY}
        USES_TERMINAL
        VERBATIM
        )

#This target allows one to depend on the custom command from another file
add_custom_target(${name} 
    DEPENDS ${CUSTOM_OUTPUT}
    VERBATIM
    )
```

The issue is that when I am actually working on this, I generate the figures on one machine, save the Postscript images files to the git repository, and then work on the actual latex document on a laptop.  The laptop can't handle running the executable, and honestly I would like to have some fairly tight controls in general about if and when a figure is regenerated.  *Ideally the Postscript files would only build if they are missing.*  It would also be nice if the Postscript files rebuilt if the dependencies (e.g. the executable source files) changed since first config, but that may be asking too much.

This is easy enough to do in config time, but doesn't really the case where a file is deleted post-config.

I've tried something like this (where the output is the Postscript files):

```
#same custom command as before, but we also generate a copy.  This copy should always be newer that the output
add_custom_command( OUTPUT ${CUSTOM_OUTPUT}
        COMMAND ${CUSTOM_COMMAND}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CUSTOM_OUTPUT} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/copy/
        DEPENDS ${CUSTOM_DEPENDS}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CUSTOM_WORKING_DIRECTORY} #usually this is ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
        ${USES_TERMINAL}
        VERBATIM
        )


#for every output make a command that makes the copy depends on the original output.  So that they are always up to date if they exist.
foreach(arg IN ITEMS ${CUSTOM_OUTPUT})

    if(EXISTS ${COPY_OBJ})
         file(COPY ${arg} DESTINATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/copy/")
    endif()
    list(APPEND CUSTOM_TARGET_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/copy/${arg}")


    add_custom_command( OUTPUT  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/copy/${arg}
         DEPENDS "${arg}"
    )

            
endforeach()

#now have the target depend on the copies which are always up to date with the original outputs
add_custom_target(${name}
    ${CUSTOM_ALL}   
    DEPENDS ${CUSTOM_TARGET_DEPENDS}
    VERBATIM
    )
```

This doesn't work, and I'm not sure if this is because these operations are occurring in a source folder, or if I'm misunderstanding of add_custom_command up-to-date logic.

Note: This is different from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785168/cmake-check-if-file-exists-at-build-time-rather-than-during-cmake-configuration) where they only test for existence.  I'm trying to change up-to-dateness with existence.

Comment: Your requirement "Ideally the Postscript files would only build if they are missing." **contradicts** to "It would also be nice if the Postscript files rebuilt if the dependencies (e.g. the executable source files) changed since first config". Actually, you may check (or pass via `cmake` option) whether generator executable is available. And create `add_custom_command` only when the generator is available.

Comment: To the first point: its not a contradiction because i specified that it rebuild only if the dependencies change _after first config_.  So a clean directory with the images files would just build the document, but then, after config, and only after, if i changed the executable source files, then i would expect all the dependencies to rebuild.  Again, i doubt cmake can be that nuanced.

Comment: To your second point.  I am not sure what would are saying would work.  Do you mean check with an if or a generator expression?  What are you calling generator in this?  As far as i know you can only conditionally make a custom_command at config, which is specifically not what I am trying to do.

Comment: Well, the logic of `add_custom_command` is to run command when either OUTPUT is not existed or OUTPUT is older than at least one of DEPENDS. You may create an `add_custom_command` with a Postscript file as OUTPUT and source files as DEPENDES. But also at configuration stage you may check existence of a Postscript file ([with if(EXISTS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html)), and if the file exist, `touch` it (which makes timestamp of the file equal to the current time). So, the existed file won't be rebuilt unless source source file becomes newer that configuration time.